# Minecraft closes after I click Login

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've tried every solution I've found online. Please can someone help me with this. Here is the log. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x4cddd09f, pid=3928, tid=856
#
# JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4dev32.dll+0xd09f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x4b421800):  JavaThread "Minecraft main thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=856, stack(0x4bf80000,0x4bfd0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00ab9888, ECX=0x4cd22ffc, EDX=0x00ab85a0
ESP=0x4bfcf19c, EBP=0x4cd22ffc, ESI=0x4cd74a74, EDI=0x4cd22ffc
EIP=0x4cddd09f, EFLAGS=0x00010216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4bfcf19c)
0x4bfcf19c:   4cd22ffc 4cd74a74 4cd22ffc 00ab9888
0x4bfcf1ac:   4cd22ffc 4cd74a74 00ab9888 4cddd529
0x4bfcf1bc:   4cd29694 4cc64804 4cc92260 4c8fad6e
0x4bfcf1cc:   54010d4f 00adfb70 00b2c478 4bfcf330
0x4bfcf1dc:   54010d4f 00b2fd14 4cd22ffc 00ae7fd0
0x4bfcf1ec:   4bfcf83c 4cc163e1 ffffffff 4cace414
0x4bfcf1fc:   54010d4f 00ab1390 00010000 4bfcf350
0x4bfcf20c:   54010d4f 00000000 67342ac0 4bfcf2f4 

Instructions: (pc=0x4cddd09f)
0x4cddd07f:   08 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x4cddd08f:   cc 83 ec 0c 53 55 56 57 8b f9 8b 87 f4 1a 05 00
0x4cddd09f:   8b 08 8b 51 08 8b 87 ac 1c 05 00 3b 87 b0 1c 05
0x4cddd0af:   00 8d af 78 1a 05 00 89 7c 24 10 89 54 24 18 89 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00ab9888 is an unknown value
ECX=0x4cd22ffc is an unknown value
EDX=0x00ab85a0 is an unknown value
ESP=0x4bfcf19c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4b421800
EBP=0x4cd22ffc is an unknown value
ESI=0x4cd74a74 is an unknown value
EDI=0x4cd22ffc is an unknown value


Stack: [0x4bf80000,0x4bfd0000],  sp=0x4bfcf19c,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ig4dev32.dll+0xd09f]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nCreate(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PeerInfo;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+10
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Context.<init>(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PeerInfo;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Context;)V+104
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Drawable;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;)V+88
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+9
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a()V+174
j  asq.a()V+94
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run()V+6
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x4b421800 JavaThread "Minecraft main thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=856, stack(0x4bf80000,0x4bfd0000)]
  0x4b449c00 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4092, stack(0x4bd10000,0x4bd60000)]
  0x4b44a000 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5652, stack(0x4b920000,0x4b970000)]
  0x01c8a800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=6024, stack(0x01b30000,0x01b80000)]
  0x4b17d000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5692, stack(0x4b570000,0x4b5c0000)]
  0x4b174000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6112, stack(0x4ab40000,0x4ab90000)]
  0x4b173800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5980, stack(0x4b4c0000,0x4b510000)]
  0x4a169000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5848, stack(0x4aaf0000,0x4ab40000)]
  0x4a120800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=6068, stack(0x4aaa0000,0x4aaf0000)]
  0x4a120400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4600, stack(0x4a750000,0x4a7a0000)]
  0x4a00ec00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6064, stack(0x4a2b0000,0x4a300000)]
  0x4a004800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5500, stack(0x4a260000,0x4a2b0000)]
  0x49ffdc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5656, stack(0x4a210000,0x4a260000)]
  0x49ffbc00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4544, stack(0x4a1c0000,0x4a210000)]
  0x01c72000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1036, stack(0x49f70000,0x49fc0000)]
  0x01c6d400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4532, stack(0x49f20000,0x49f70000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01c66c00 VMThread [stack: 0x49ed0000,0x49f20000] [id=5844]
  0x4a022800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x4a300000,0x4a350000] [id=4024]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 92913K [0x03d10000, 0x0e7b0000, 0x19260000)
  eden space 139776K,  66% used [0x03d10000, 0x097cc460, 0x0c590000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x0c590000, 0x0c590000, 0x0d6a0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x0d6a0000, 0x0d6a0000, 0x0e7b0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 0K [0x19260000, 0x2e7c0000, 0x43d10000)
   the space 349568K,   0% used [0x19260000, 0x19260000, 0x19260200, 0x2e7c0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12581K [0x43d10000, 0x44990000, 0x47d10000)
   the space 12800K,  98% used [0x43d10000, 0x44959718, 0x44959800, 0x44990000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x49b10000,0x49d40000] byte_map_base: 0x49af1780

Polling page: 0x00bc0000

Code Cache  [0x01c90000, 0x01ea0000, 0x03c90000)
 total_blobs=1276 nmethods=1000 adapters=210 free_code_cache=30672Kb largest_free_block=31407744

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 8.925 Thread 0x4a004800 1003   !         java.net.URLClassLoader$1::run (73 bytes)
Event: 8.926 Thread 0x4a004800 nmethod 1003 0x01e97808 code [0x01e97950, 0x01e97b88]
Event: 8.941 Thread 0x4a004800 1004   !         sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier::setEntry (299 bytes)
Event: 8.944 Thread 0x4a004800 nmethod 1004 0x01e97f88 code [0x01e98280, 0x01e98cd0]
Event: 8.987 Thread 0x4a004800 1005             java.security.Provider::ensureLegacyParsed (123 bytes)
Event: 8.988 Thread 0x4a004800 nmethod 1005 0x01e99e88 code [0x01e9a040, 0x01e9a348]
Event: 8.990 Thread 0x4a004800 1006             sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier::verify (272 bytes)
Event: 8.991 Thread 0x4a004800 nmethod 1006 0x01e9a588 code [0x01e9a770, 0x01e9ad4c]
Event: 8.996 Thread 0x4a004800 1007             java.util.jar.JarFile::maybeInstantiateVerifier (96 bytes)
Event: 8.997 Thread 0x4a004800 nmethod 1007 0x01e9b608 code [0x01e9b780, 0x01e9ba04]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 8.996 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x095fbbe0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 8.996 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x095fbfb8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.002 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x09611850 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.002 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x09611c90 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.003 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x09615180 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.003 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x096155a8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.004 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x0961ba00 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.004 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x0961be60 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.006 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x0961e450 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 9.006 Thread 0x4b421800 Threw 0x0961e900 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u10\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166

Events (10 events):
Event: 8.996 loading class 0x4a075e50
Event: 8.996 loading class 0x4a075e50 done
Event: 9.002 loading class 0x4b37ab78
Event: 9.002 loading class 0x4b37ab78 done
Event: 9.003 loading class 0x4b37a9b8
Event: 9.003 loading class 0x4b37a9b8 done
Event: 9.004 loading class 0x4b3176f0
Event: 9.004 loading class 0x4b3176f0 done
Event: 9.006 loading class 0x4a089588
Event: 9.006 loading class 0x4a089588 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00bd0000 - 0x00bff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x77bc0000 - 0x77d27000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x76460000 - 0x76558000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x75300000 - 0x753bd000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x715d0000 - 0x71677000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x765e0000 - 0x7668e000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x766c0000 - 0x767e1000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x73bf0000 - 0x73de7000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.16384_none_893961408605e985\COMCTL32.dll
0x761c0000 - 0x76271000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763c4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x75890000 - 0x75962000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x76280000 - 0x7638a000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76690000 - 0x766bb000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75a30000 - 0x75b0d000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x67370000 - 0x6742d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x65c30000 - 0x65f7c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x6fee0000 - 0x6fee8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x71800000 - 0x71821000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x75750000 - 0x75756000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x77980000 - 0x779d0000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x717d0000 - 0x717fa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x75cd0000 - 0x75cd8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x724d0000 - 0x724dc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x70b30000 - 0x70b50000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x70a00000 - 0x70a13000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x65ae0000 - 0x65c22000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
0x778f0000 - 0x7797b000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x75610000 - 0x75746000     C:\Windows\system32\combase.dll
0x743b0000 - 0x74457000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x73df0000 - 0x73e09000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x77a20000 - 0x77b39000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x75060000 - 0x75069000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x75000000 - 0x75051000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x76800000 - 0x778c6000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x779d0000 - 0x77a10000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77bb5000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
0x705e0000 - 0x7060a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x695a0000 - 0x695b4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x74b80000 - 0x74bca000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x724c0000 - 0x724cf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x72980000 - 0x72990000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x74a10000 - 0x74a85000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x6ed40000 - 0x6ed49000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x6c3f0000 - 0x6c400000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x6c3d0000 - 0x6c3e4000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x6f1e0000 - 0x6f201000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x72280000 - 0x722a0000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x72390000 - 0x72398000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
0x72350000 - 0x7238f000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6f1d0000 - 0x6f1d7000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74bd0000 - 0x74bea000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x748f0000 - 0x7492e000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x749c0000 - 0x749db000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x751d0000 - 0x751e1000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x69470000 - 0x69490000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\sunec.dll
0x68d70000 - 0x68da1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\t2k.dll
0x76560000 - 0x765d4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
0x72df0000 - 0x72f36000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x70d20000 - 0x70d29000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x753c0000 - 0x75548000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75250000 - 0x75262000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x4bf10000 - 0x4bf7b000     C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\natives\lwjgl.dll
0x672a0000 - 0x6736e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll
0x704e0000 - 0x704e8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x68d40000 - 0x68d63000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x65a00000 - 0x65ad9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
0x709f0000 - 0x709f7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x70520000 - 0x70526000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jawt.dll
0x4c8d0000 - 0x4ccc2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig4icd32.dll
0x4cdd0000 - 0x4d06a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig4dev32.dll
0x64200000 - 0x64329000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
java_command: C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\mc\Minecraft.exe
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
USERNAME=Dave
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8 Build 9200 

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 2087316k(1171344k free), swap 4184468k(2640304k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.6-b04) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_10-b18), built on Nov 28 2012 08:34:29 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Dec 25 13:40:44 2012
elapsed time: 9 seconds
```

Comment: Briefly, do other Java applications work?  Is Java up-to-date?

Answer (score 3):

```
C  [ig4dev32.dll+0xd09f]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nCreate(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PeerInfo;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+10
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Context.<init>(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PeerInfo;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Context;)V+104
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Drawable;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;)V+88
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+9
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a()V+174
j  asq.a()V+94
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run()V+6
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

These lines tell you that there is a problem in the call into the ig4dev32.dll library. It happens when a function of this file is called from org.lwjgl.opengl. `lwjgl` is a library that is distributed with Minecraft.

Usually, such problems are caused by

- a buggy client (i.e., Minecraft. This is unlikely since then many people would experience the same problem and it would be fixed rather soon.)
- a buggy library (a quick search will reveal that `ig4dev32.dll` is part of the OpenGL library. this is also unlikely, since then a massive number of people would experience this bug.)
- incompatible versions of the client and the library. This is the most likely case.

It may be that installing some other software replaced the `ig4dev32.dll` file with another version that is incompatible with the one that `lwjgl` assumes to be present. I suggest you update your OpenGL library by **updating your graphics card driver.**

If this does not help, you might want to consider telling us what you already tried.

Comment: Another option is to replace the lwjgl files included with Minecraft with the newest version of those files. Minecraft tends to release with out of date versions of lwjgl.